# Is there a way to import a folder structure in Vite

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I have a bunch of sub-folders plus a few `.vue` components in the  `src/pages` folder. With webpack I was able to get a list of the page paths and name with code like this:

```
export default require
  .context("../pages", true, /^\.\/.*\.vue$/)
  .keys()
  .map(page => page.slice(2).replace(".vue", ""))
  .filter(page => page !== "Index")
  .map(page => ({
    file: page,
    title: createTitle(page),
    path: slugify(kebabCase(page))
  }));
```

Vite doesn't seem to support this. I tried `const pages = import.meta.glob('../pages/*.vue')` but this only works for files, not files inside sub-folders.

Any idea how I can achieve this with Vite?

Answer (score 11):

I found a way. It's not perfect but not terrible either:

```
const pages = import.meta.glob('../pages/*.vue')
const folders = import.meta.glob('../pages/*/*.vue')
const both = {...pages, ...folders}
export default both
```

This is a refinement:

```
const pages = import.meta.glob('../pages/**/*.vue')
export default pages
```

Comment: For reference: https://vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#glob-import

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like [vite-plugin-pages](https://github.com/hannoeru/vite-plugin-pages) :

installation :

```
npm install -D vite-plugin-pages
```

which requires vue-router to be installed :

```
npm install vue-router
```

Add to your `vite.config.js`:

```js
import Pages from 'vite-plugin-pages'

export default {
  plugins: [
    // ...
    Pages(),
  ],
}
```

Router config :

```js
import { createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import routes from '~pages'

const router = createRouter({
  // ...
  routes,
})
```

There're also other plugin like `unplugin-vue-components` to resolve components and `vite-plugin-vue-layouts` to resolve layouts